# Costmap shows free space as obstacles

Tags: slam, gazebo, navigation, uav, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!
I am trying to use navigation stack on quadcopter equipped with kinect sensor at Gazebo simulation. I am using grid_map topic of rtabmap_ros package as map for navigation of UAV which hovers at 1.5 m over ground. But global_costmap and local_costmap both show free space on proj_map as obstacles ([proj_map](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YyllM2rQbt_oY-FTz9cQz773kt-lXzUL), [global_costmap](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LRdps5-RMNQ_-UKA2Ig9dhHqxv7vjHh4)). How can I fix it?

Costmap common params:

```
footprint: [[-0.2,-0.2],[-0.2,0.2], [0.2, 0.2], [0.2,-0.2]]
inflation_radius: 0.65
cost_scaling_factor: 10.0

obstacle_layer:
  obstacle_range: 5.5
  raytrace_range: 6.0
  max_obstacle_height: 0.7
  track_unknown_space: true
    
  observation_sources: point_cloud_sensor
  point_cloud_sensor: {
    sensor_frame: quad/camera__link,
    data_type: PointCloud2,
    topic: /quad/camera_/depth/points,
    marking: true,
    clearing: true
  }
```

Global costmap params:

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_link
  update_frequency: 1.0
  publish_frequency: 1.0
  static_map: false
  plugins:
     - {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
```

Local costmap params:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 5.0
  height: 5.0
  resolution: 0.02
  tranform_tolerance: 0.5
  planner_frequency: 1.0
  planner_patiente: 5.0
  plugins:
     - {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291617/costmap-shows-free-space-as-obstacles/) by [Fedor](https://answers.ros.org/users/34630/fedor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2018-05-18**:
Can you show a screenshot of the Gazebo environment? Can you share the `rtabmap.db` too?

**Comment by [Fedor](https://answers.ros.org/users/34630/fedor/) on 2018-05-20**:
Sure. [Screenshot of the Gazebo environment](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15FLJswHpeRqRodEKCPayRGmzFfVID5c3), [rtabmap.db](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iaECWXHJe4aWB9E-XBBTH78orblujzwZ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the database you shared, the depth image seems strange because the trees are mostly big polygons with texture. But with this input data, the occupancy grid is generated correctly though.

Using rtabmap-databaseViewer, raw point cloud with RGB+depth image (on left all local occupancy grids assembled) :

[image: image description]

3D Segmentation based on `Grid/` parameters (note that as `Grid/RangeMax` is 4 meters, the cloud is cut up to 4 meters):

[image: image description]

Then the projected 2D grid for this image:

[image: image description]

**EDIT**

In your `obstacle_layer`, you take the whole point cloud of `/quad/camera_/depth/points` as obstacle, including the ground. It is why the ground is seen as an obstacle in the costmap. You may use a filtered cloud from  `/quad/camera_/depth/points` without the ground instead. If the drone is flying always at the same height, it would not be so difficult to filter the ground (like with a pcl_ros [passthrough](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Tutorials/PassThrough%20filtering)). In contrast to this [example](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/StereoOutdoorNavigation) with a ground robot, if the drone is moving also in Z and/or the ground is not flat, you may want to keep the ground as obstacle and use the 3D map/OctoMap output of rtabmap for 3D navigation (with [moveit](https://moveit.ros.org/)?).

For the `Grid/RangeMax` parameter, if you have an older rtabmap version, the parameter is called `Grid/DepthMax` (`Grid/DepthMax` is automatically converted to `Grid/RangeMax` if the version supports it). To have more points to project at longer distance, you can also set `Grid/DepthDecimation` to 1 (default 4) at the cost of more computation time.

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2018-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fedor](https://answers.ros.org/users/34630/fedor/) on 2018-05-21**:
Thank you for answer.
So, my issue is related to costmaps: global and local costmaps show free space at grid_map as obstacles. Costmaps blink ([pic1](https://goo.gl/XBVyzm), [pic2](https://goo.gl/viXrxe), [pic3](https://goo.gl/Sen9tq)), though grid_map remains the same. What may be the problem?

**Comment by [Fedor](https://answers.ros.org/users/34630/fedor/) on 2018-05-21**:
I deleted parameter `Vis/MaxDepth` and added `Grid/RangeMax` with a value of 9, but cloud is still being cut up to 4 meters. Changing `Grid/RangeMax` to 2 doesn't change cut up distance.

**Comment by [Fedor](https://answers.ros.org/users/34630/fedor/) on 2018-05-22**:
Neither `Grid/MaxDepth` nor `Grid/RangeMax` haven't changed cut up distance - maybe problem somewhere else.
I have added `rtabmap_ros/obstacles_detection` nodelet and have changed point cloud source in costmaps to `/cloud_obstacles` topic. It has fixed my problem, thanks for your help!